# .NET DataContractJsonSerializer DateTime format

Tags: c#, .net, json

Does anyone know where I can find documentation on the `DateTime` Format used by the .NET `DataContractJsonSerializer` class? I have been looking for a while but can't find it. First, I know you can provide your own format by passing Settings to this class, however, if I use the default format, I want to be able to document that. Basically if someone decided not to use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class to deserialize my json string, they would know how to convert a `DateTime` object back to their native DateTime type. Or is that something that's unique to DataContractJsonSerializer class?

For example:

```
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();  
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DateTime));
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString());        // "6/26/2018 5:37:31 PM"
ser.WriteObject(stream1, now);
ms.StartPosition = 0;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);  
Console.WriteLine("JSON DateTime Format: ");  
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());        // "\/Date(1530049051609-0400)\/"
```

So where is the documentation for "6/26/2018 5:37:31 PM" -> "1530049051609-0400" -> "6/26/2018 5:37:31 PM"? Or is there any.

Comment: `ser.WriteObject(stream1, now.ToString());`

Comment: @Hackerman kind of defeats the purpose, since you would be serializing `string` and not a `DateTime`?

Comment: You can work with that, so it should be no problem...anyway, first we need to understand what JSON stands for `JavaScript object notation`...so `Date(1530049051609-0400)` its a valid javascript date. In fact, if you paste `Date(1530049051609-0400)` in your browser console, you should see something similar to `"Wed Jun 27 2018 13:27:32 GMT-0400 (hora estándar de Chile)"`

Comment: Yes, I thinks its obvious that JSON can be read by multiple languages, but still missing the point of the question, which is asking for specific documentation on the .net json serializer format conversion methodology, not a workaround.

Comment: No, you don't get it, at least I tried...

Answer (score 1):

Using the following I was able to serialize a DateTime object and then deserialize it.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

string json = "";
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DateTime));
    ser.WriteObject(ms, now);
    byte[] jsonByte = ms.ToArray();

    json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonByte, 0, jsonByte.Length);
}

DateTime? deserializedDateTime = new DateTime();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))) {
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedDateTime.GetType());
    deserializedDateTime = ser.ReadObject(ms) as DateTime?;
}

Console.WriteLine("Object to JSON:");
Console.WriteLine(json);
Console.WriteLine("JSON to Object:");
Console.WriteLine(deserializedDateTime.ToString());
```

As far as documentation goes, I used the following sites and modified some example code from the.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC). The -0400 is your time zone offset.